# Contact Form 7 Input text should get only particular value or else show error

Tags: wordpress

In WordPress Contact Form 7, if someone enters a value in Input field it should match the exact text/number condition or it should not submit the form.

Is there a way to do like that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is way to do it. You can use Conditional Fields for your purpose.

Plugin [Conditional Fields for Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/)

[Documentation](http://bdwm.be/wpcf7cf/how-to-set-up-conditional-fields-for-contact-form-7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<label> Your Email (*required)
    [email* your-email placeholder " example@example.com" ] </label>

<label> Your Phone (*required)
[tel* your-phone placeholder "123-456-7890" ]
    </label>
```

you can mention like this.. if suppose in the phone number field ,,anybody put a name ,,it didnt submit the form,..hope it helps